# Create a header when exporting from netcdf to csv using python

Tags: python, csv, header

In Python I'm trying to export a csv file after reading a NETCDF. Currently I don't have headers in the csv. Can someone help me to write a header. Thanks in advance.

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset("../../Data/PYthon/s_daq5_evap_20180825_e56.nc")
evap_pos = ds.sel(lat=-38.2,lon=145.9,method='nearest').compute()
evap_out = evap_pos['evap']
#evap_out.plot()

evap_csv = pd.Series(evap_out, index=ds['time']) 
evap_csv.to_csv('evapout56.csv',index=True, header=True)
```

Comment: Your code writes a header here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create header to write it  to file. For example:

```
evap_csv.name = 'data value'
evap_csv.index.name = 'index value'
```

Then your csv-file first line will be: `index value,data value`